# Building R package Using Rcpp

Tags: rcpp, devtools, r-package, rcpparmadillo

When I perform devtools::check(), the log tells a note:

```
checking compilation flags used ... NOTE
  Compilation used the following non-portable flag(s):
    ‘-march=core2’ ‘-mssse3’
```

Does anyone have a clue about this note and how to get rid of it?
My R is of version 4.1.0 and I am using a mac

Comment: Likely harmless. Those come from R, you can find them in the file `${R_HOME}/etc/Makeconf`, ie `Makeconf` in the `etc/` directory of your R installation, and reflecting choices made when your R was compiled.  Are you using the macOS binary from CRAN or from `brew` ?  (Or you could have added them in `~/.R/Makevars`.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel TBH I don't know where my binary comes from, I installed r-base via Anaconda. Are you suggesting adding them to my package's Makevars file?

Comment: No you do not need to add them, they are already there (due to Anaconda choices). And you cannot easily get rid of them. But you *can* have your package build at RHub or Win-Builder, and you will likely see _no such warnings_ precisely because this is *not* part of your package (but simply part of how R does things).